# Good practice loading UIImage

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimage

I have a few icons in my app that I reuse in multiple views (for example a favorite icon).

In order to save memory, I was wondering if using a class with class methods which loads static images would be a good idea ?

For example :

```
+ (UIImage *)favoriteIcon {
    static UIImage * icon;
    if (!icon)
        icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite.png"];
    return icon;
}
```

Or should I just use `+ (UIImage *) imageNamed:(NSString *)name` every time I need ?

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` is already doing something like this under the hood. In fact, it's smarter, because it is also doing things like dumping the images when memory is low and they aren't needed right away, while your `favoriteIcon` method keeps them loaded forever.

In general, it's better to avoid doing optimizations like this until you've built your app and then profiled it to see how/where it needs improvement. Otherwise you are wasting time or maybe even making things worse. I recommend you learn how to use Instruments to profile your app, it's kind of complicated but a lot of fun once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I would add that using `UIImage imageNamed:` is great for small images such as for icons. It is poor practice to use `UIImage imageNamed:` for large images unless the image is shown throughout the lifetime of the app. Transient, large images should be loaded with `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:` (or similar).

Comment: Prefect, thank you for all your informations. Exactly what I needed.