# keep or remove subviews when loading new – Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have an app with different pages, each with subviews like imageviews and button. My question is what's best to do when loading the new page. When a button is tapped on the first page a new UIView appears with different subviews. Should I remove the old page and its subviews or keep them? On the new view I have a button that should lead back to the first page, so if I would remove them when adding the new page I would have to initialize them agin.

What should I do to get it as smooth as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218197/good-practice-loading-uiimage) a few months ago.
Basically, the answer is :

**In general, it's better to avoid doing optimizations like this until you've built your app and then profiled it to see how/where it needs improvement.**.

Code, get it working, and then, learn how to use [Instruments](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks), to detect **where** and **when** to optimize your app !

Good luck with iOS development.